# Arranging rulebased symbology alphabeticaly

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend, rule-based

QGIS version 3.16.4

I'm working with a layer that has a lot of different items in rulebased symbology. But they seem to be ordered randomly. Is it possible to arrange them alphabeticaly?
I'm hoping that with this I can also have them show up alphabeticaly in the legend, now its just a big mess. The legend shows a smaller selection of the items, so I'm also fine with arranging them myself in the legend...but that's also not possible

Here a picture of the legend I want to make alphabeticaly:
[image]

And a picture of the symbology page: (not all items are shown)
[image]

And here a picture of what the layers look like in regards to each other:
[image]

Comment: More information, please.  For example, what QGIS version?  When you use the term "legend" that implies that you are using a layout; is that the case?  What have you tried so far?  Screenshots would help.

Comment: I've added the information

Comment: @stu-smith the user Aanders have added the information. Do you have any ideas to answer his question?

Comment: The OP has not yet answered whether or not this will be used in a layout.

Comment: Sorry I havent replied before, I didn't notice the notification. I do indeed use a layout. But also just in the layers on the homescreen it would be nice to have them in order.

Comment: @stu-smith  the OP said, that he wants to use it in a layout.